# How to get glare on "Quick Smoke" (Fire & Smoke explosion)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, smoke-simulation

I have this question that relates to Blenders Quick Smoke tool. Recently I have been rendering CGI explosions and smoke assets to be keyed in later on a short film, but I have this small problem that I think would make the explosion look a ton better, but I just cant quite figure out how to do it. Now as we may also know using composting, you can have a glare node on specific light sources to make the scene a lot more realistic, but Im trying to figure out how to do it with explosions. As seen below I rendered out this fairly simple explosion but I would really like it to have a glare to the flame parts of it.

[image: Expolision 1]

Thanks if anyone has any ideas, also a quick side question as well, is there a way to hide the emitter (The sphere in the middle) [Cycles]. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can check this video, as well as increasing the emission strength of the fire material

https://youtu.be/ctd_09qHacA?t=35m3s

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the response, however; im not looking for a way to increase the Fire Emission, instead, adding some sort of glare filter to the image, as you would if you where compositing an image. Now that im thinking of it i may have to do it out side of blender and somehow how add some filter in post. 

But thanks!

Comment: In the video explains how to add the glare filter in the Blender Compositor, the comment about increasing the Fire Emission was because maybe you want to increase the intensity of the glare filter, and to do that, you need to increase Fire Emission

Comment: Okay thanks! i will make sure to check it out once i'm on my computer, thanks for the help!

Comment: This site is not based on solutions accessible via external links, they can quickly expire, please describe your answer directly in your post.